# How to find the MD5 hash of a file?

Tags: autohotkey, md5, checksum

Given a file with a known file path, how can you generate an MD5 hash for the file in AHK, without reimplementing the entire MD5 hashing algorithm in the code, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631582/how-do-i-generate-md5-of-a-string-in-ahk-windows-10/67420104#67420104) post does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the Windows CertUtil tool to find the MD5 hash sum and Parse the output by [StrSplit](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrSplit.htm)ing it into different lines (The MD5 sum itself will be on the second line).

cmd command used:

```
CertUtil -hashfile %appdata%/appsettings/app.ini MD5
```

(Note: replace `%appdata%/appsettings/app.ini` with your actual file path)

---

Final Code:

```
var:= ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /q /c CertUtil -hashfile %appdata%/appsettings/app.ini MD5").StdOut.ReadAll()
MsgBox %var%
outputArr := (StrSplit(var , "`r`n"))
out:=outputArr[2]
MsgBox %out%
```

It is tested for `Windows 10`, although it should work for some older versions as well.